# Which join method is comparatively better for eg: (+) or Right outer join

Tags: outer-join

In terms of performance, which join method is better.
And what are the drawbacks doing this way

Tab1.col1 = Tab2.col2(+)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Oracle developed their (+)syntax before the ANSI committee had completed the definitions for the joins.
```

And no there is no performance difference.

Read more about it : [Oracle Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Joins.html#GUID-29A4584C-0741-4E6A-A89B-DCFAA222994A)